# Fourier series Parseval equality with partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f \in \mathcal{R}_\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$ be function with period $2\pi$. We denote n-th partial Fourier series sum of function $f$ with $S_n(x)$. Prove that:

> $$
> \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(f(x)-S_n(x) \right)^2dx = \pi\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(a_k^2+b_k^2)
> $$

I know that Parseval equality(is it called identity?) is true:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^2(x)dx = \frac{a_0^2}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k^2+b_k^2)
$$

I tried the following (without much loss of generality I have assumed that $a_0 = 0$) to obtain Parseval equality back:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(f(x)-S_n(x) \right)^2dx = \pi\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(a_k^2+b_k^2)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^2dx -2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)S_n(x)dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}S_n(x)^2dx \right)= \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(a_k^2+b_k^2)
$$
Now, we have:
$$
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)S_n(x)dx  = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\left[\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^n\left(a_kcos(kx) + b_kcos(kx)\right)\right]dx =
$$
$$
 = \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)a_kcos(kx)dx+ \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)b_kcos(kx)dx =
$$
$$
 = \sum_{k=1}^na_k\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)cos(kx)dx+ \sum_{k=1}^nb_k\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)cos(kx)dx =
$$
$$
 = \sum_{k=1}^na_ka_k+ \sum_{k=1}^nb_kb_k =
$$
$$
 = \sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+ \sum_{k=1}^nb_{k}^2 = \sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+b_k^2
$$

So the main equation is now:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^2dx -2\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+b_k^2  + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}S_n(x)^2dx \right)= \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(a_k^2+b_k^2)
$$

I feel like I got closer, because I have the $a_k^2 + b_k^2$ sums from 1 to n and from n+1 to infinity. Is that correct line of reasoning? How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Continue computing $\int S_n^2$, which will be another sum up to $n$, and $\int f^2$ which you know is the sum up to $\infty$.

Comment: The Parseval identity is equivalent to the $L^2$ convergence of the Fourier series for an $L^2$ function. This is, in turn, equivalent to the $L^2$ convergence for all $f$ in a dense subspace of $L^2$. One such dense subspace is the continuously differentiable periodic functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$. For such functions, you can prove the uniform convergence of the Fourier series, which then implies the $L^2$ convergence. That's one way to prove what you want.